# Android ICS x86 on VirtualBox with Internet Connection

Tags: android, emulation, android-x86

as you can probably think I want to install Android ICS in VirtualBox. I have, but I doesnt have Internet connection. I tried servel tutorials for the last hours but it does not work. I dont want to use the Android Emulator. So can somebody help me? how do you get Internet acces in the Virtual Mashine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working on this right now, specifically with ethernet, I found [this google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86/browse_thread/thread/30fa23d81cddfab1/2e480f6b9cbf773d) 
 very helpful. Basically what you are going to need to do apply a few patches from two of the users in the discussion, and one from google source for the right menu options. The user "tablet-x86" provides a link to an iso with working ethernet (but not his source).

From what I could tell this is the best you are going to get until Android-x86 adds in this support (I am using Android-x86 project and not Google source)